# if foo = "4.3" why does foo == ("4.3" || "4.4") equal true, but foo == ("4.4" || "4.3") equal false?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Shouldn't they both be true or am I missing something?

I'm trying to write an if statement that matches a variable to a set of options. I can always do: 
`if (variable == "4.3" || variable == "4.4")`

but wouldn't the other way be shorter and still work?

Comment: that isn't an `in` function. you are short doing `if foo == 4.3` only. you can use `Array.prototype.indexOf`

Comment: The values in the parenthesis are going to get evaluated before the `foo ==`

Comment: if the first value is falsey (null, false, 0), then the second value is returned.  try `var x = null || ''`, which is a common way to default a value to an empty string if no value has been assigned.

Comment: You have to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What your code is effectively doing is

```
foo == "4.3"
```

and the second is

```
foo == "4.4"
```

It is not operating as an in or comparing to either value. It is evaluating "4.3" || "4.4" and using the first truthy value. In the first case, "4.3" and in the second case "4.4" because of the order of the values.

You could use the following to act as an in:

```
(["4.3","4.4"]).indexOf(foo) > -1
```

You can add more values to the array to match against if appropriate later.

Answer (score 2):

Parenthesis are evaluated first, and the `||` operator returns the first "truthy" value.

`foo == (“4.3” || “4.4”)` is true because the right side of the `==` evaluates to `"4.3"`

`foo == (“4.4” || “4.3”)` is false because the right side evaluates to `"4.4"`

Answer (score 2):

The || section calculates first and the following is returned

```
"4.3" || "4.4"
```

returns "4.3"

And

```
"4.4" || "4.3"
```

returns "4.4"

So you are then checking

```
variable == "4.3"
```

And

```
variable == "4.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

That `||` is the "OR" operator in javascript, but in the context of your statement you are saying "return which ever is truthy":

```
var foo;
foo = (0 || 1); //1
foo = (13 || 14); //13
foo = (null || undefined); // undefined;
foo = ("4.4" || "4.3"); //"4.4"
```